# External replacing global variable in browser (webpack)

Tags: javascript, webpack, external

I'm using the `externals` option to specify the `xmlhttprequest` module as an external. This worked fine in version `2.2.1`. I specify the external as follows:

```
  externals: {
    "xmlhttprequest": "XMLHttpRequest"
  }
```

In the `.js` file, I have the following code:

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  // Seems like we are using Node.js
  var XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
}
```

which worked perfectly fine.

I decided to switch to the *latest* version (`3.3.0`), and now my project gives an error when used on the browser: `XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor`. So for some reason, it seems to override the global `XMLHttpRequest` variable.

Which is weird, because if I call `new XMLHttpRequest()` in the console, it works fine.

When using Node.js, the global variable `XMLHttpRequest` should be replaced by the external module. In the browser, the global variable should remain *unaffected*.

---

When I remove the line

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
```

it works fine again in the browser. Also when I rename the variable. But when I change the external to something like this (and keeping the above line unaffected):

```
xmlhttprequest: 'abcd'
```

it still fails.

See my repository [here](https://github.com/wagenaartje/stocks.js). If you replace the variable name `NodeXMLHttprequest` with `XMLHttpRequest` and then compile it with webpack, it won't work anymore for the browser.

Comment: Have you tried to debug through the bundle to see what exactly happens and why?

Comment: @zerkms I wouldn't know where to start. I just switched versions and it stopped working. I went through the changelogs but I couldn't see `externals` mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Open a bundle file and read it?

Comment: @zerkms I have. I have checked what has changed in the bundle when switching to the newer version, and it only seemed to change some numbers around: `(this, function(__WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_0__) {` became `(this, function(__WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_1__) {` and this line got removed `__webpack_require__.i = function(value) { return value; };` and `module.exports = __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_0__;` got removed... I can't geta  hang of what happened...

Comment: It's really not productive. You should not compare them. Make up the smallest possible code to reproduce the issue (you have already done it, those are literally 2 lines of code). Then create a bundle out of it. Then read those 20 or 30 lines of the resulting bundle and find your issue. If necessary - take a debugger and step through literally every line until you find which breaks your runtime. That's how you debug your code.

Comment: See my repository [here](https://github.com/wagenaartje/stocks.js). If you replace the variable name `NodeXMLHttprequest` with `XMLHttpRequest` and then compile it with webpack, it won't work anymore for the browser.

Comment: I have explained how you could debug it yourself. Now it's up to you whether you do it and solve your problem or wait for a miracle.